Modeling $-\ln(1 - w \cdot \sigma(x))$ as disciplined convex programming
Given $0 < w \leq 1$, I would like to use the function:
$$
-\ln(1 - w \sigma(t)),
$$
where $\sigma(t) = 1 / (1 + \exp(-t))$ is the sigmoid function, in my objective. It's a bit tedious, but this function is convex. But I was not able to find any DCP representation of this function so that I can incorporate it into CVXPY. Note, that when $w = 1$ this is the loss function of a negative event in logistic regression, so the case of $w = 1$ is easy.
Update
My bad.. it is not convex, as pointed out in one of the answers.

It doesn't look particularly convex:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v17plvovb8.


My bad... indeed it is not. Going to look for the mistake.
